# NSFetchedResultsController in one to many relationship

Tags: ios, core-data

I have this one to many relationship entities. An `NSFetchedResultsController` was used for a table view to display list of teams.  This part I understand and it works fine.  Now in this teams table view if one selects a team, another table view will display list of members.

Currently I use an array to hold the objects from the members set, like so:

```
NSArray *membersList = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[aTeam.members allObjects]];
```

But this second stage is not clear to me.  Should I need to do another `NSFetchedResultsController` using the selected team name as a fetch predicate for the members list table view instead of expand the fault as I did above?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to track changes in those items (Members), or the data set is very large, you should use a FRC.
If your data is not updated from an external source, and is relatively "small" you could just use the relationship as your datasource.

The FRC is made for you to track changes and access your data in an efficient way (fault and un-fault objects by need, batch fetching ...).